# How to add child to existing data in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How would I do to add a child to existing data in a Firebase database through an Android application? Here is what my Firebase database looks like:

[image]

I want to be able to save data as children to the parent values in the image, so that I can have lists of values. The problem is that I do not know how to reach these existing values with auto-generated id's from my application, I want to be able to save a value as a child to the current choice of value in a spinner.

Here is the code that pushes the "lists" to the database:

```
private void onAddListClick()
{
    String text = listEditText.getText().toString();
    String refPath = "CategoryList";

    if (text.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(refPath);

        myRef.push().setValue(text);

        listEditText.getText().clear();

        finish();
    } else
        {
            //...
        }
}
```

And here is the code that is supposed to save the value/task in the correct list depending on the spinner choice:

```
private void onAddTaskClick()
{
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("CategoryList");

    String text = taskEditText.getText().toString();
    String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if (text.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        list.add(new Task(text));
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        taskEditText.getText().clear();

        //Change me!!
        //myRef.push().setValue(text);

    } else
        {
            //...
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**
A possible solution to my question would be to get hold of the auto-generated id and then to add a child to that existing value. I know there are other questions with answers for getting the id instantly when pushing the value to the database, however I want to be able to get the id later when I want to add a child to the already existing value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. When you run the code you shared, what does it do? And what do you expect it to do?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When `onAddTaskClick()` is run, I want it to save the text as a child to the list that is chosen in a spinner, for example I want it to be saved as a child to "A List" in the image above. Right now when the code under the `//Change me!!` comment is run it just pushes the value into the Firebase database as a new value. I want that line to be changed so that it saves the value as a child to a list. Hope this made sense.

Comment: @AlexMamo The code is not giving me any errors however it is not giving me the result that I desire. In the example above I have two lists currently, in the app I choose one of those lists in a spinner and my desire is to be able to add tasks to that specific list so that the added task will be saved as a child to that list in the firebase database instead of just pushing a new value next to the lists, I want it to be a child value of the list. Hope that clarifies my issue and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If `spinnerValue` is the key in the database of the item they clicked in the spinner, you can add a child to that node with:

```
String spinnerValue = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

if (text.trim().length() > 0)
{
    list.add(new Task(text));
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    taskEditText.getText().clear();

    myRef.child(spinnerValue).push().setValue(text); //  change here
} else
```

Comment: Actually `spinnerValue` is just a String with the name of the actual list, so what the above code does is just add a new value of, for example, "A List" with a child to it. I guess what I need to have in place of the `spinnerValue` would be the auto generated id, but how would I go about getting a hold of that? Or is there a simpler way to do what I want to do?